# Convert list in String format back to list of float numbers

Tags: python, regex, django, python-3.x

```
str = [  3.82133931e-01   4.27354313e-02   1.94678816e-03   0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00   3.61185198e-06   1.26606241e-01   1.18472360e-01]
```

The above string has been retrieved from a database text field and I'm trying to convert it back into a list of floats however no matter what I try I can't seem to get rid of the square brackets.

```
floatList = []

for k, v in enumerate(str.split('   ')):
    if re.search(r'\d', v):
        item = re.sub(r'\D\S', '', v).rstrip()
        item = re.sub(r'\[.*?\]/g', '', item)
        floatList.append(float(item))
```

I have tried:

```
item.replace('[', '')
item.replace(']', '')
```

and with the Ascii codes.

Always the error **ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[ 536444501'**

Comment: is `str = ` actually part of the string?

Comment: @mgilson no that's just the variable I'm holding it in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you should be able to just strip off the `[` and `]`:

```
str = str.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
```

And then split the string calling float on each member of the split string:

```
floats = [float(x) for x in str.split()]
```

Notice that because python strings are *immutable*, things like:

```
str.replace('[', '')
```

Doesn't change `str` in place.  Instead, it returns a *new* string with the requested characters removed.  Since it *returns* a new string, we need to give that string a name (I just chose to give it the name `str`<sup>1</sup> again to avoid using too many names...)

<sup><sup>1</sup>Note that `str` is also not a good name for a variable since it shadows the builtin `str` *type*.  I would highly recommend picking a different name :-)</sup>

Comment: You answered the question and pointed out the mistake I was making not binding the str.replace output to a new variable.

Comment: @Sayse -- good point.  I've added a footnote explaining why `str` is a bad name for a variable :-).

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
floats = [ float(x) for x in re.findall('\d+\.\d+e[+\-]\d\d', str)]
```

Comment: worked thanks, although for the sake of readability I'm going with @mgilsons answer

Answer (score 1):

You should be storing your numbers in your database as floats rather than strings.

If you're using postgres you can make use of the [`ArrayField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield)

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
my_floats = ArrayField(models.FloatField())
```

If you're not, you should still store them as numbers but it may require a different relational model.

Comment: I'm using sqlite because I'm only working with a single table. I greatly reduced the size of the array for convenience, which is actually a the color histogram of an image.
Could you maybe expand on what relational model would be practical?

Comment: @LukeVincent - In the past I've needed a separate table for arrays which is essentially made up of just a floatfield with a wrapper and a foreign key back to an array model that is then used in my models as needed. The point is that trying to fit square pegs in round holes always tends to cause issues at some point

Comment: I think if I were to do that I might as well change to a Postgres database which I potentially will do. Thanks for the advice anyway.